# Is it possible to debug a C# console application using git bash?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, cmd, git-bash, .net-6.0

I am using Visual Studio Community 2022, and I was wondering if you could use another CLI to run/debug a c# console application. (I can't use cmd.exe or powershell because it's blocked by the admins of the device I'm using). Git Bash would be preferred, because it's already installed. Thank you!

Edit: Looks like you can't do this. `dotnet run` just tries to open the blocked binary, no matter where you run it. I think the admins hate everyone though because they allow you to install lots of things (like Unity, vscode, etc.) but running anything just doesn't work.

Thanks for trying everyone!

Comment: Is cmd.exe (the binary) blocked, or just its location at c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe?

Comment: Sounds like something you should discuss with the admins of your device :)

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar the binary is blocked sadly

Comment: I agree with @MathiasR.Jessen - you need to work with admins of the device since you claim pretty much everything (including `dotnet` and I assume CSC) is blocked. There is probably good reason for it (also I'm quite surprised how VS is even installed there). If you decide to clarify the question consider adding target framework too...

Comment: Try sticking to check Microsoft Docs dotnet run for more options, CLI: Use Vs2022 Terminal in View->Terminal

Answer (score 2):

use this to run your program in CLI but you cannot debug it if you want to debug use debugger mode of vs2022,

If it's a framework-dependent application (the default), you run it by `dotnet yourapp.dll`.

Run the project in the current directory:

```
dotnet run
```

check [Microsoft Docs dotnet run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-run) for more options.

CLI: Use Vs2022 Terminal in View->Terminal it may help You to run it.

Comment: Doesn't work, because its the cmd binary thats blocked, so even trying dotnet run in git bash won't work.

Comment: Use vs2022 Terminal in Veiw->Terminal

Comment: @AbolfazlMoslemian if "dotnet" is blocked too (as they indirectly said) there is not much OP can do I'm afraid.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov yes I agree With you. if 'dotnet' also blocked, he have to call system admin :) .......